# Table - Scroll to Bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I made a chat system using PHP and its not like other chat system, I have put some unique stuff, It uses a table and in each table-row It shows a message so its like the messages or any code is well ordered and put in design, but when the comments are loaded, The box which contains that table is scrolled to top as any usual page or div does, I want to make it scroll to bottom on every chat-box refreshing so it works like a chat box.

Comment: Can you post your current HTML markup and (preferably) a demo page on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Okay, I forgot to to accept those answers, Now check. I accepted some useful answers...

Answer (score 1):

Basicly , you can do something like that:

In your jQuqery , For any comment added , append a:

```
<a name='last_comment'></a>
```

and remove it from the comment before.
So you'll have only one `last_comment` anchor - after the last comment.

In the same function , use `trigger` with a `click event` on that anchor link.

Comment: I am sorry, But I don't even Know how to create a variable in JQuery, I just want to attach a short script that scrolls down the table so, Users can see the latest chat comment that others have posted.

Comment: So you should start reading about `jQuery`. About your question , read about `append` , `trigger` , `ajax`. I gave you the main idea of how-doing-it.

Comment: Not relevant , there's no `major` different betwen `div` to `table` , when using `jQuery`.

Comment: @OfirBaruch 
So, Is this usefull?
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("your_div");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;

Comment: Add your javascript (or jquery) code to your question please , I will modify it.

Comment: Okay, Now I understand clearly what you saying, You saying is that:
I load every row or comment then give tham an index last_comment, then go for refreshing the box again and delete the last_comment index from previous comments and add it to the new one, right? Then how to scroll to that index?